# Create and open a bootstrap modal window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, instance

I want to replace my current dhtmlx modal window with a bootstrap modal window. My application currently use a container to store the dthmlx modal window's instance and use it.

```
myContainer = new dhtmlXWindows();
```

I want to do the same with bootstrap but I cannot seem to be able to open a bootstrap modal instance, even in JSFiddle.

I found [an exemple of what I want to do](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Modal-Dialog-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-3-Bootstrap-3-Dialog/examples/) that looks like this:

```
var dialogInstance = new BootstrapDialog({
   title: 'Dialog instance',
   message: 'Hi Apple!'
 });
 dialogInstance.open();
```

But this code does nothing in [the JSFiddle I created to test it](https://jsfiddle.net/davidgourde/arnp24e5/).

Would you have an idea on how to resolve my problem? I don't want to use HTML code to create the dialog, I need to have that in JS like in my fiddle.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Using init options
        var dialogInstance1 = new BootstrapDialog({
            title: 'Dialog instance 1',
            message: 'Hi Apple!'
        });
        dialogInstance1.open();
        
        // Construct by using setters
        var dialogInstance2 = new BootstrapDialog();
        dialogInstance2.setTitle('Dialog instance 2');
        dialogInstance2.setMessage('Hi Orange!');
        dialogInstance2.setType(BootstrapDialog.TYPE_SUCCESS);
        dialogInstance2.open();
        
        // Using chain callings
        var dialogInstance3 = new BootstrapDialog()
            .setTitle('Dialog instance 3')
            .setMessage('Hi Everybody!')
            .setType(BootstrapDialog.TYPE_INFO)
            .open();
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.5/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.5/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
```

Refer: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Modal-Dialog-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-3-Bootstrap-3-Dialog/examples/

Refer: http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/jQuery-Modal-Dialog-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-3-Bootstrap-3-Dialog.html

Comment: Yes, but this is not using an instance. I can use `.show()` and it works correctly, but not when using an instance, like `myContainer = new dhtmlXWindows();`, which is how I need to use it.

Comment: Lol, this is exactly the code I pasted in my question. Anyway, it showed me it worked. The reason mine did not work is because of the lack of the bootstrap dialog js files. I thought the bootstrap.js file had everything... Thanks anyway